# HTML href points to non-existent source files but still seems to load fine?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to html and I'm trying to fix up a website I acquired. Everything I can find on href and forward slashes points to it being a local file, but nothing like that path exists in GoDaddy.

Example code excerpt that takes you to a working page:

```
<a href="/websites/view/new-listings"><?=_('Latest' ) ?></a>
```

Screenshot of GoDaddy file directory and the total lack of that path (even though the page loads without a hitch):

[image]

Example code excerpt that doesn't work but I would like it to work:

```
<?php echo '<a href="/listings/' . $l->listingID . '/' . url_title($l->listing_title) . '" class="url-listing-title"><i class="icon icon-tag"></i> ' . $l->listing_url . '</a>';?>
```

The variables here all seem to be loading up fine, it's just the `/listings/...` path that 404's.

Edit: 
.htaccess shows this, but I'm not sure what it means exactly.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And then here's index.php if that helps:

```
<?php
set_include_path(getcwd() . '/application/views');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

if(!function_exists("_")) {
    function _($string) {
        return $string;
    }
}


/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *()
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Comment: I dont use php but i think this is called URL routing. Mostly used in SPA (single page apps). The view folder index.php maybe accepting the query in the url after view and process the html or do some actions base of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **cpanel file directory** there is no **listings** folder, so its throwing 404 error. Check for `.htaccess` file if there is **rewrite rule** for `websites`.

Comment: perfect, that's what i'm looking for. What does the code mean? I put it in an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Its not always, necessary that you'll always find the exact local file path, corresponding to the URL.

As in Apache Server, we can edit .htaccess file to route certain URL calls to some resource. This is used to hide the exact file name of the script from public, so as to implement an extra layer of security.

So be sure, to check the .htaccess file .